# mod_rewrite getting rid of port number in favor of directory

Tags: mod-rewrite

How do I mod_rewrite `ip:4040` to `ip/streamer` ?

I have application at `ip:4040` but it is hard for users to remember port number.
So I created directory `/var/www/streamer`

And now I'm creating apache virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/streamer

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule / :4040 

</VirtualHost>
```

Obviously rewriteRule is incorrect, but having no idea of regex, any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your web server is also listening on port 80, as well as 4040:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  4040
RewriteRule .*            http://xxxxxxx/   [L,R=301]
```

Where **xxxxxxx** is the server host name or IP, without a port number.